# Normalise likelihood scores to probabilistic interpretation

Tags: probability

I have 3 numbers, which represent the log-likelihood. I need to normalise them so that they can be interpreted in a probabilistic manner. The challenge lies in the fact that some log-likelihoods are negative and some are positive.

What I'm currently doing is that given 3 numbers as a matrix `X` is:

```
X = (X - min(X))/max(X)
```

This normalises the data with minimum to 0, maximum to 1, and the third value in between them.

Are there any other suggestions on what I can use? I need to combine two likelihood scores to come at a decision, and that is why I need to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how likelihood could be negative, can you give an example of the $3$ numbers. and I guess you equation should be as you brought but with small change: $x= (x -min(x))/(max(x) -  *min(x)*)$

Comment: @d_e : I meant the log likelihoods. Have fixed it. Also, what advantage does the change proposed by you give me?

Comment: It makes true your assertion of a "maximum to 1".

Comment: @Did: Thanks. I just realised that I was doing the subtraction and division in two steps, and thats why my maximum was 1. So the expression for X I wrote above was wrong.

Comment: Indeed, `(X - min(X))/max(X-min(X))=(X - min(X))/(max(X)-min(X))`... :-)